# problem: interaction between magrittr and operators packages

Tags: r, operators, magrittr

After I installed the "operators" package, the %>% pipe operator presents problems.

Hi everyone! Greets from a recent user of R. I had installed the "magritte" package and ran this code:

```
CuencasRN <- "cuencas_rn.csv" %>%
  read.table(header = F, check.names = F)
```

It had worked very well. After that, I installed the "operators" package (because I want the %!in% operator) and I ran the same previous code, with the following error:

```
Error in read.table(header = F, check.names = F) : 
  argument "file" is missing, with no default
```

The only solution I found was uninstall the "operators" and reinstall the "magrittr" packages.

Any suggestion? I really want to use the "operators" package but "magrittr" stops working well.

Thank you (sorry about my english!)

Comment: If all you want from the operators pkg is the negation of `%in%`, that seems like a lot to do for a function that is literally nothing but `!match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) > 0L`. (Look at the code for `%in%` and write your own that just negates the result.)

Comment: thank you @joran, actually `!a %in% b` instead of `a %!in% b` works well for my purposes

Comment: You don't need to uninstall or reinstall packages.  What matters is the order in which they appear on the search list.  At the start of a session (before either package has been attached), do `library(operators); library(magrittr)` and the `magrittr` definitions will have priority.